# How to detect when the user takes a screenshot out of the application?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swift4

How to `detect` when the user takes a `screenshot` out of the `application` or `application` is not in active stage? I want to fire a push notification when user take screen shot out of the app or anywhere from `iphone`.

like this app :- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/liketoknow-it/id1154027990

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot is a springboard event. This is not possible unless the application is active or in a jailbreak environment

Comment: it's working on pinterest app that is live on the app-store but i don't know how to achive this that's why asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what is the need of screenshot when app is not running as it will be screen shot of your device home screen, not the application. So it is not possible.

**This is the solution when your app is running.**

Here, UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot will comes into the picture, `screenshotTaken` will be called for below case. Yes you have to create `screenshotTaken` method on your controller.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(screenshotTaken), name: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil)
```

You can try below option too

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.userDidTakeScreenshotNotification, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { notification in
    print("Screenshot taken!")
}
```

Comment: it's my app requirement to detect this and this is happen in pinterest app that is live on the appstore thats why i asking here.

Comment: Did you need to give the Pinterest app permission to read your photo library?  If so it probably just looks for new screenshot sized photos

Comment: no but app is closed that time how possible to get all new screenshot ?

Comment: check now my question i put the link of app in it

Comment: That app asks for access to your photo library, so that is how it is detecting screenshots. I wasn't willing to allow it access to my photos so i couldn't test it fully

Comment: It is only working if you are in the app. Not when app is in background....

Answer (score 0):

Using this code detects screenshots.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot,
                                               object: nil,
                                               queue: OperationQueue.main) { notification in
            print("\(notification) that a screenshot was taken!")
        }
```